# How to verify a RESTful service that returns a HTTP 404, using Fancordion?

Tags: rest, fantom, afbedsheet

I'm writing a RESTful API in [Fantom](http://fantom.org) programming language. I'm using [Fancordion](http://www.fantomfactory.org/pods/afFancordion) to write the acceptance tests and have this scenario:

Country.fandoc

```
Country by Code
###############
Passing a country code as a parameter to the Country RESTful service must return the corresponding country
Example
-------
- Given the URL to get the details of Andorra [/country/AD]`set:countryUrl`
- When I send a HTTP GET request to it
- Then I expect the name to be [Andorra]`verifyEq:countryByCode.name`.
```

CountryFixture.fan

```
using afBedSheet
using afBounce
using afButter
using afFancordion
using util

@Fixture { specification=`specs/Country.fandoc` }
class CountryFixture : BaseFixture {

  Str? countryUrl

  Country countryByCode() {
    server := BedServer(AppModule#).startup
    client := server.makeClient
    response := client.sendRequest(ButterRequest(`$countryUrl`)).asStr
    Str:Obj? json := JsonInStream(response.in).readJson
    country := Country.fromJson(json)
    return country
  }
}
```

This works well. Now I want to verify that when an invalid country code is passed to the request, the RESTful service returns a HTTP 404 error, which it does, as I've implemented and verified using the browser. However, I haven't found in Fancordion documentation how can I verify that a HTTP 404 error is returned. What I'm getting instead is a fixture failure.

```
***
*** 1 Fixtures FAILED [6 Fixtures]
***
```

My acceptance test for this scenario is (appended to Country.fandoc):

```
Wrong Country Code
##################
Passing a wrong country code as a parameter to the Country RESTful service must cause it to return a HTTP 404 error

Example
-------
- Given the URL to get the details of country that does not exist [/country/XX]`set:countryUrl`
- When I send a HTTP GET request to it
- Then I expect a HTTP 404 error when I try `verifyEq:countryByCode`
```

How can I catch the 404, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something similar to a `verifyErr(Type errType)` method, Fancordion doesn't have one. That's because such methods are closely coupled to the implementation which doesn't really suit the style of Fancordion tests.

Instead, disable the 404 Err raised by [Butter](http://www.fantomfactory.org/pods/afButter) with:

```
client.errOn4xx.enabled = false
```

And have the Fancordion fixture set the response.

```
Uri? url
ButterResponse? response

Void httpGet() {
  client := BedServer(AppModule#).startup.makeClient
  client.errOn4xx.enabled = false
  this.response = client.get(url)
}
```

Then let the Fancordion specification verify the status code:

```
Example
-------
- Given the URL to Unknown is [/country/XX]`set:url`
- When I send a [HTTP GET request]`exe:httpGet`
- Then I expect the returned status code to be [404]`eq:response.statusCode`.
```